# Get the row that does not contain some data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggeling with a SQL query

I'm trying to get the `ChildId` that Both of his\her parents(  `Some_Code_Of_Parent`) does not contain specific data(50 in this case).

```
 ParentId | ChildId | Some_code_of_Parent 
 11       |    2    |                  50    
 22       |    2    |                   0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Please be aware that this table contains many similar data of many children and parents. These are only two rows as an example.

In this case I would like to have a result with 0 rows. 
In case both of the Parents(11,22) had a value of 50 in `Some_code_of_Parent` then the result would be 1 row with the Child's Id.

Comment: question is not clear.

Comment: What are the parameters for the criteria? Agree with @Amit, this isn't very clear. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Provide sample given and desired data please.

Comment: I have no idea why somebody thought this question was worthy of an upvote. This question lacks any kind of detail required for anybody to anything much more than guess.

Comment: What are the data types of your columns. Are all of them int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return only those childId where every parent has Some_code_of_Parent = 50.

```
DECLARE @valueToCheck INT = 50

SELECT DISTINCT ChildId FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ChildId NOT IN(
SELECT ChildId FROM TABLE_NAME a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE ChildId = a.ChildId AND Some_code_of_Parent <> @valueToCheck))
```

or

```
DECLARE @valueToCheck INT = 50

SELECT DISTINCT ChildId FROM TABLE_NAME  WHERE ChildId NOT IN(
SELECT ChildId FROM TABLE_NAME  WHERE Some_code_of_Parent <> @valueToCheck 
GROUP BY ChildId, Some_code_of_Parent)
```

or

```
DECLARE @valueToCheck INT = 50

SELECT ChildId FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY ChildId 
HAVING avg(cast(Some_code_of_Parent as decimal(20,2))) = @valueToCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    ParentID 
From MyTable 
Where Some_Code_Of_Parent <> 50;
```

Or for multiple values like 50, 100, 150

```
Select 
    ParentID 
From MyTable 
Where Some_Code_Of_Parent Not In (50, 100, 150) And Some_Code_Of_Parent Is Not Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT 
    ChildId 
FROM 
    MyTable 
GROUP BY 
    ChildId 
HAVING
    MAX(Some_code_of_Parent) = MIN(Some_code_of_Parent)
    AND MAX(Some_code_of_Parent) IN (0,50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sub query and not in condition.

```
Select distinct ChildId from [Table] 
where ChildId not in (select ChildId from [Table] where Some_code_of_Parent = 50)
```